# How can an pointer of superclass access variables of subclass?

Tags: c++, function, variables, pointers, inheritance

I have a class A and class B which inherits from class A. Class B has a variable and a function that are not available in class A. I made a pointer

```
A* ptr=new B();
```

So how can ptr access the variable and function that belongs to class B?

Comment: Search for and read about *downcasting*.

Comment: Asking two unrelated questions in one post is not recommended - you will get partial or confusing answers. You can [edit] your question to leave only one question in it, or replace them by a more general one.

Comment: As for your second question, if you have *one* virtual member function, you just have *one* function in the base class that the child-classes override. It will "just work".

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation. I delete the second question.
About the second question. I mean, class A has 25 subclass (class B, class C,...) and each subclass has it own unique function (function B of class B, function C of class C,...). So I have to create virtual function B, virtual function C... in class A in order to allow the A* ptr to use them? Is this the best solution?

Comment: Joachim Pileborg is correct.  However, I suggest you invest a few minutes of your time to understand why it will "just work".  These basic nuances of the language are extremely important for you to know.

Comment: The correct answer is **via class A virtual functions**. Ignore what you hear about downcasting.

Comment: The correct answer is **downcasting**. Ignore what you hear about virtual functions. [JK]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class A simply cannot "see" the functions of class B.  Instead, you'd have to use something like a dynamic_cast from A to B, check for null, and then proceed as you like.  [Here is a nice tutorial to explain this a lot better than I can.](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/)  Each of the casts have their advantages and disadvantages; learn them well.  Also, try to avoid C style casting.

EDIT : Seems I misread the question.  The answer is still correct, though.  Class A would not be able to "see" the variables of Class B.  The casting would still allow you access to them.

Comment: I created a `B* ptrB`, used dynamic_cast by `ptrB=dynamic_cast<B*>(ptrA)` and it worked! Thanks for you answer soulsabr.

Answer (score 0):

You can force the derived class to implement a pure virtual method defined in the base class:

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual void do_things() = 0;
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    virtual void do_things()
    {
        //Implementation
    }
};
```

This way you can call the method implemented by class B through a pointer `A*`:

```
A* a_ptr = new B();
//The method implemented in class B will be called
a_ptr->do_things();
```

You could also make the assumption that `a_ptr` points to an object of class B. If `a_ptr` doesn't point to a `B` the pointer returned by `dynamic_cast<B*>` will be a `nullptr`. You can use `static_cast<B*>` if there are no virtual methods in `A`.

```
b_ptr = dynamic_cast<B*>(a_ptr);
b_ptr->do_things;
```

This way you don't need the pure virtual function in class A.

Comment: dynamic_cast return a null to b_ptr if a_ptr didn't point to an object of type B.  You are thinking static_cast.

Comment: I cannot access the unique variables of class B with 1st solution. The 2nd solution works well to me. Thanks!

Comment: You could make a method  which returns a reference to the variable you need.